# Prove $(aba)^k$ = $ab^ka$ for all K in W iff $a^2 = e$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove $(aba)^k$ = $ab^ka$ for all K in W iff $a^2 = e$. a,b are elements of a group.

I'm not sure where I am supposed to start.

Comment: Did you try multiplying elements together...?

Comment: Since folks have shown the 'if' part, here's a hint towards the 'only if': take $k=2$ so that the equation you have is $(aba)^2=ab^2a$.  Now expand out the left, and try multiplying both sides of the equation by $b^{-1}a^{-1}$ on the left, and $a^{-1}b^{-1}$ on the right.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Start by proving by induction on $k \in \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ that:
$$
(aba^{-1})^k = ab^ka^{-1}
$$

Comment: Do you mean for $k \in \{1,2, \ldots \}$? Otherwise taking $k=0$ we're done from the start - I'm not sure we can do this for groups.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align*}
(aba)^k &= \underbrace{(aba)\cdots (aba)}_{k\ \textrm{times}} \\
 &= \underbrace{ab\color{red}{a}}_{k\ \textrm{of these}}\color{red}{a}b\color{green}{aa}b\color{blue}{aa}b \cdots \color{orange}{aa}ba \\
 &= ab\color{red}{e}b\color{green}{e}b\color{blue}{e}b \cdots \color{orange}{e}ba \\
 &= \cdots
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 0):

More general

$$(a^n b a^m)^k = a^n b^k a^m$$

iff $$a^{n+m} = e$$